# The Fastest Way To Alloc 1000000 NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, performance

Normally, we would create 1000000 `NSObject`s this way.

```
NSMutableArray* objs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    MyObject* o = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    o.str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    [objs addObject:o];
}
```

However, this can be very slow. Maybe a lot of the memory allocation should be merged, or there is some other trick to speed it up.

How do I allocate space for several thousand `NSObject`s more time-efficiently?

Addition:
Using **malloc** to get a huge number of memory, and re-init it, is also illegal. Since converting from a normal memory into a NSObject will failed with bad access. See below:
[image]

Comment: If you have performance problems of this kind, usually you should go for pure C and `malloc`.

Comment: @Sulthan But I need a ObjC object in my code.

Comment: is it your homework or why do you need 1M objects allocated at the first place? do it on a background thread – as we are talking about 2-4 secs at most in case of initing 1M objects anyway; that must not be a critical issue in practice but seems senseless...

Comment: @holex :). It's the problem I met in my project. Malloc 1M of memory is fast. But I can't convert it into ObjC object, since it will crash by bad access. I don't know why, too.

Comment: Could you describe your use case a bit more? I think that you are not reducing the problem correctly. Your problem won't be how to allocate 1M object fast but instead the problem will be the need to allocate them in the first place? Maybe using a better algorithm or a different architecture would solve the problem more effectively. And there is *always* a way to use pure C, you just have to define correct interface with the Obj-C part.

Comment: @Ringo_D, so you _don't_ have a problem with allocating the memory you _do_ have a problem with keeping the object alive by a strong reference...?

Comment: @holex Yes, as the title said, "The Fastest Way To Alloc 1000000 NSObject".

Comment: @Sulthan My problem is how to alloc a huge number of "NSObject" in a fast way. The point is, a kind of "NSObject". Not a C++ class or a raw memory.

Comment: @Ringo_D The only way to create a new object in Objective-C is calling `alloc` & `init...`. If you need better performance, don't use Objective-C objects, they are high level structures with their own memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no short-cut to this problem.  If you need to allocate 1 million objects then it will take time and possibly fail due to consuming too much memory.

Given that limitation you need to think about a different solution.  For example if each of these objects represents some *item* then have an `ItemManager` object that manages as many of these items as necessary.  The manager class can then allocate memory in *chunks*, rather than for individual items, and this will perform much better and be more scalable.

However given you don't explain exactly what these objects represent, I cannot provide a more detailed alternative.